# Is there a way to let hibernate auto manage database?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

Hibernate automatically performs some updates such as creating tables or columns, but don't changing types of columns. For example we are changed column type from `long` to `int` and column type in database still `bigint` (PostgreSQL 9.5). Also, we added type converter for LocalDateTime fields, and Hibernate creating new field as `timestamps` but don't changing type of old fields. How can we configure Hibernate to let it automatically manage such things?

Comment: Not possible with hibernate, you should do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

While I think this practice is pretty bad, and very dangerous, the reality is you just need the right permissions.

Most SQL databases store the database information in a system schema.  The user for your app would have to have permission to utilize and possibly CRUD that schema.  Once you have that, it is just a matter of writing the hibernate classes to manage the tables.

For example, if I wanted to change the schema a particular table belonged to I can do that by executing this statement in PostgreSQL:

```
update pg_tables set schemaname = 'newSchema' where tablename = 'xxx';
```

Allowing your application to do so opens you up to all kinds of pain and suffering.  Including faults that are expecting a certain data model that was dynamically updated; and, if your application is hacked you could have all your tables dropped.